# How to access a variable in the ready event within charts_google.js without hacking the chart module?

Tags: charts, dashboard

I need to be able to respond to the ready event within the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module.

I have [Homebox](https://www.drupal.org/project/homebox) installed and one of the blocks used in it is a google chart. The homebox resize action takes place before the chart has finished rendering and is misalligned.

I need to call the homebox resize action from the chart ready event. Currently I have added this code to the charts_google.js file, which works fine but I need to move it out of the chart module into my custom module.

```
function myReadyHandler(){ // added this
  Drupal.homebox.equalizeColumnsHeights();
}

function renderCharts() {
 ...
 google.visualization.events.addListener(wrap, 'ready', myReadyHandler); // added this
 ...
}
```

The variables in question is wrap. How can I get access to this variable in my own module without hacking charts_google.js?

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at issues [#1196712](https://www.drupal.org/node/1196712) and [1715638](https://www.drupal.org/node/1715638), which seem to be like variations of your request.